# How to find a trekking buddy

Tags: trekking

Unfortunately none of my friends seem to be very interested in trekking through Sweden. However, you can't just pick a random person and say: "Let's go!", can you? I mean it's the only contact person for a week or so.

Is there a website or something where people may get in touch?

Comment: Is this question still relevant for you? I’m in the similar situation now, looking for hiking companion in Sweden, maybe we can do it together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try starting a discussion on the [couchsurfing page](http://couchsurfing.com/) of the given Swedish region saying that you would like to do this or that type of trekking, for given period and difficulty, preferably include what gear would be needed; this way locals and nearby travelers may contact and join you, but beware: there is no warranty that the potential trekking partners would match your experience or expectations.

Also, check out the local scout troops: if they have the rover/adult age category, you would most probably find people interested in trekking.

Answer (score 5):

There are websites you can use to find others with a similar interest in expeditions - for example, have you tried http://www.explorersconnect.com/ ? It is specifically for people looking for advice and companions for longer trips and expeditions.